# UI Adjustable Matplotlib Color Range

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, scipy

I am using Python's scientific plotting library `matplotlib`. I am trying to use `matplotlib` to show an image using `imshow`. I would like to be able to adjust the color range with in the figure with some type of UI. From what I can tell, there isn't a built-in way to do this in `matplotlib`, and I have found much on this issue. This is a fairly common use-case and easy to do in MATLAB. How does one do this in `matplotlib`?

Comment: When asking how something, which can be done in *A*, can be accomplished in *B*, you should explain or at least link to an example of how it's done in *A*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to change the `cmap` attribute. You could use the built-in function `input` to read some new value from the command line (not really a GUI) or you could use the `matplotlib.widgets` package which includes e.g. a slider and buttons ([see this link for examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/examples/widgets/index.html)).

Comment: Well, it's been a while, and I guess your answer is as good as its going to get. I'll investigate using the widgets, I'm just surprised that it's that it's not already fairly standard behavior.